# More than one face match found using face_recognition library in python

Tags: python, face-recognition

I am currently using face_recognition library in python for facial recognition with `compare_faces()` method. However, it matches my face with someone else's face too. Is there any modifications I could make in my code to get better results, or are there any other methods in the same library that I could use? Also, suggestions of any other python libraries for face recognition that have better results will be appreciated. The code I am using has the following method:

```
results = face_recognition.compare_faces([known_encoding], unknown_encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at OpenCV for Python (  https://opencv.org/  ) be sure to read the documentation to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the tolerance like so

`results = face_recognition.compare_faces([known_faces], unknown_encoding, 0.5)`

The lower the tolerance (in this case 0.5), the stricter the tests are.